# Add single value from stored procedure to Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

We have a stored procedure `Taxable` that returns one row with 5 entries. It takes two parameters, `ID` and `type`, and I am trying to use one entry only (`[MonthlyFeeTax]`) in a select statement.

All of the other values are being selected from a table UDF, the stored procedure is from a vendor and I can't change it.

```
Exec Taxable (51, 'Client')
```

returns the following for this client:

| Income | Expenses | Payments | MonthlyFee | MonthlyFeeTax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3000 | 2200 | 200 | 25 | 1.25 |

I want to use the monthly tax calculated for a specific creditor as below but can't get this in and am looking for the best approach. I know the case statement is wrong but it indicates the outcome I am looking for. How can I get the single value from the `Taxable` stored procedure into this query? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    id, accountnumber,  [Balance], payment,            
    CASE
        WHEN CreditorID = 1 
            THEN Exec Taxable (51, 'Client')
            ELSE NULL
    END AS [Taxes]
FROM
    [dbo].[AccountBalances] (51, 'Clients')
```

Comment: Idea lly convert the procedure to an inline Table Valued Function, then you can do `SELECT ... FROM YourFunction(51, 'Client');`

Comment: @Charlieface `The Stored Procedure is from a vendor and I can't change it.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert... exec...` syntax to get the result from the procedure into a table variable you can use. Since you know only a single row is returned you can simply embed a subquery into your query:

```
declare @Output table (
  Expenses decimal,
  Payments decimal,
  MonthlyFee decimal,
  MonthlyFeeTax decimal
);

insert into @Output exec Taxable(51, 'Client');

Select id, accountnumber,  Balance, payment,            
  Case CreditorID when 1 Then (select MonthlyFeeTax from @Output) End Taxes
from dbo.AccountBalances(51,'Clients');
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the direction